# Can Burp detect new REST APIs exposed on a server

Tags: api, rest, burp-suite

I am trying to write an automated test that runs on all exposed APIs on a server and checks each endpoint for vulnerabilities.

The problem is the server I am testing always has new APIs exposed, so I want my test to automatically detect new APIs exposed and then run the scan on them. Is that feasible?

I found [this link from burp](https://portswigger.net/burp/documentation/scanner/scanning-apis). It says that

> API scanning works in a similar way to web page scanning, but instead
> of crawling for web content Burp Scanner crawls for exposed API
> endpoints

Does that mean Burp can do what I am looking for? Scanning a server and detecting the exposed REST APIs?

Comment: Does the server list the available API endpoints anywhere? No tool can just 'detect' API endpoints. They need to be listed somewhere, such as an OpenAPI specification. Or, in other words, how would consumers learn about these new API's?

Comment: That link also says: "By default, Burp Scanner attempts to scan any API definitions that it encounters as part of its regular crawling activity." So ... if it uncovers the definitions during crawling, then yes...

Answer (score 0):

According to Burp documentation, you can use Burp Professional or Entreprise with the "Burp Scanner" functionality to scan APIs, but only if it has an API definition.

> The specification of the API definition must be OpenAPI version 3.x.x,
> and based on either JSON or YAML. The API definition must not contain
> any external references.

If your API definition does not follows the above or does not exists, you can still try use Burp Profesional with the "[Content discovery](https://portswigger.net/burp/documentation/desktop/tools/engagement-tools/content-discovery)" feature, but it will likely be much slower than using a definition.

Comment: When you say it detects only if there is API specification, you mean just in case the crawler detect api specificatoin files, but those file may be on the server but couldn't be detected by the crawler. Right?

Comment: The API definition may or not be publicly accessible. It may be unsecure depending on the application and business domain. Burp can either detect automaticaly such files during or the user can use a hand supplied URI endpoint. It is not written anywhere in the documentation that it could not be a local URI. In fact It is not uncommon that pentesters can audit systems in a isolated environment.